# ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, image, properties, undefined, typeerror

There is some issue with line having CardImg. It shows the error:
`'TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined'.`

I'm not able to figure out what I did wrong. Please help me out.

This is how the error looks like:
[image]

The class with error is here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle} from 'reactstrap';
import {Loading} from "./LoadingComponent";
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';


function RenderCard({item, isLoading, errMess}){
    if (isLoading) {
        return(
                <Loading />
        );
    }
    else if (errMess) {
        return(
                <h4>{errMess}</h4>
        );
    }
    else
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardImg src={baseUrl + item.image} alt={item.name} />
            <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{item.name}</CardTitle>
                {item.designation ? <CardSubtitle>{item.designation}</CardSubtitle> : null}
                <CardText>{item.description}</CardText>
            </CardBody>
        </Card>

    );

}

function Home(props){
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row align-items-start">
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.dish} isLoading={props.dishesLoading}
                    errMess={props.dishesErrMess}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                <RenderCard item={props.promotion} isLoading={props.promosLoading} errMess={props.promosErrMess} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-12 col-md m-1">
                    <RenderCard item={props.leader}/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: `item` is undefined, So that means  props of Home component does not contain `dish`

Comment: when I put console.log(item.name) in the RenderCard function, the console displays the name.

Answer (score 0):

[Please check these tow links for your solution]

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058505/typeerror-cannot-read-property-image-of-undefined-react)
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined/415333